# Java profiling - Tomcat server terminates

Tags: java, profiling, yourkit

I am trying to profile my spring/hibernate based application using yourkit jprofiler. Whenever I run application for profiling (along with yourkit), tomcat server terminates  after I submit the form. Data is getting insterted successfully. I get below error.

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8f6077, pid=1932, tid=5364
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode, sharing)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x136077]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid1932.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known bug and remedy

> Sun Java (HotSpot) client JVM can crash in attach mode due to a JVM
> bug
>
> Due to a JVM bug
> [6776659](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6776659)
> HotSpot client JVM can crash in attach mode.

There is no crash for the server JVM: `JVM option -server solves the problem`.

[Reference](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/95/help/attach_agent.jsp)